# Node modules not getting imported correctly in create-react-app application: 'Packer is not a constructor'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making a simple create-react-app application and trying to use a binpacking NPM package (https://github.com/jsmarkus/node-bin-packing)

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Packer is not a constructor

I'm using the NPM package as detailed in the documentation:

```
import binpack from 'binpacking'

const Packer = binpack.Packer

console.log(binpack)

const packer = new Packer(30,20)
```

The offending line is`const Packer = binpack.Packer`

The main file for the NPM package is (in its entirety)

```
exports.GrowingPacker = require('./packer.growing.js').GrowingPacker;
exports.Packer = require('./packer.js').Packer;
```

When I console log `binpack` I see that both GrowingPacker and Packer are undefined.  So it would seem they're not getting imported correctly from the sub-files 'packer.growing.js' and 'packer.js'

'packer.js' is

```
-function (exports) {


var Packer = exports.Packer = function(w, h) {
  this.init(w, h);
};

Packer.prototype = {

  init: function(w, h) {
    this.root = { x: 0, y: 0, w: w, h: h };
  },

  fit: function(blocks) {
    var n, node, block;
    for (n = 0; n < blocks.length; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))
        block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
    }
  },

  findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
      return root;
    else
      return null;
  },

  splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
    node.used = true;
    node.down  = { x: node.x,     y: node.y + h, w: node.w,     h: node.h - h };
    node.right = { x: node.x + w, y: node.y,     w: node.w - w, h: h          };
    return node;
  }

}

}(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : module.exports);
```

Finally, the directory structure of the NPM packages are

[image]

I'm at a loss here -- I'm sure it's something to do with requires or imports, but I'm lost.  I tried using 'require' in my file in place of 'import', but it changed nothing.

Comment: How about `import { Packer } from 'binpacking';`?

Comment: @horia, I tried that too, didn't work.  In the end I simply copied the JS from the node module and imported that into my app, outside of the NPM system…